# Custom predefined code template

Tags: dreamweaver

I've been looking everywhere but I'm either blind or it's really not there.

I'm looking for some option to add some sort of code template to Dreamweaver (CS5.5) which I can access with some shortcode via the code hinting menu. In Zend (PHP IDE) you could define such code blocks like

```
$query = "";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

and let Zend put them into your code when typing "qry" and hitting enter.

Is there such an option in Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'we been looking for the same and found  a solution. Try to add to your dreamweaver instalation path
"\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\CodeHints\php_codehints.xml"
into to the section

```
<menugroup MMString:name="php/CORE" id="PHP_CORE"></menugroup>
```

following code:

```
<menu pattern="$query" doctypes="PHP_MySQL" displayrestriction="PHP_Script" 
caseSensitive="true"  icon="shared/mm/images/hintKeyword.png"  
MMString:source="php/CORE" >
   <menuitem label="mssql fetch //complete" value="=&quot;
SELECT * FROM 
WHERE  
&quot;;
$Qresult = mssql_query($query);
while ($Qdata = mssql_fetch_assoc($Qresult)) {
    echo $Qdata[''];
};
" icon="shared/mm/images/hintMisc.gif"/>
</menu>
```

Now when you type **$query** to your code within PHP site, dreamweaver will offer you "**mssql fetch //complete**"

Analogically other code blocks. For example following:

```
<menu pattern="for" doctypes="PHP_MySQL" displayrestriction="PHP_Script" 
caseSensitive="true"  icon="shared/mm/images/hintKeyword.png" 
MMString:source="php/CORE" >
<menuitem label="foreach()//complete" value="each ($arr as $k => $v) {

}" icon="shared/mm/images/hintMisc.gif"/>
<menuitem label="for()//complete" value=" ($i=0; $i<=$ ; $i++) {

};" icon="shared/mm/images/hintMisc.gif"/>
</menu>

<menu pattern="if"  doctypes="PHP_MySQL" displayrestriction="PHP_Script" 
caseSensitive="true"  icon="shared/mm/images/hintKeyword.png"  
MMString:source="php/CORE" >
<menuitem label="if()//complete" value=" ( ) {

}" icon="shared/mm/images/hintMisc.gif"/>
<menuitem label="if else//complete" value=" ( ) {

}
else {

}" icon="shared/mm/images/hintMisc.gif"/>
</menu>
```

I thing this solution works on Dreamweaver since CS versions, may be in MX too.

On the other site you can simply use SHIFT+F9 and define your own code block to paste.

Comment: Sorry for the really late accept, I completely forgot about asking this.